# Context.UserIdentifier is null after switching to Azure SignalR Service

Tags: azure, signalr

My SignalR `Hub` requires users to be authenticated and the following line gives me user's Id:

```
var userId = Context.UserIdentifier;
```

Similarly, I can get the whole set of claims with:

```
var user = Context.User.Claims;
```

This works fine if I use `SignalR` locally but if I switch to Azure SignalR Service, I get a `null` value in `Context.UserIdentifier`. I also get no claims.

Here's what I'm changing in my `Startup.cs`:

In the `ConfigureServices()` method, I use

```
services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR(Configuration["AzureSignalR:ConnectionString"]);
```

instead of

```
services.AddSignalR();
```

And in the `Configure()` method, I use:

```
app.UseAzureSignalR(routes =>
{
   routes.MapHub<Hubs.MyHub>("/chat");
});
```

instead of:

```
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
{
   routes.MapHub<Hubs.MyHub>("/chat");
});
```

Do I need anything else in Azure SignalR configuration to make sure I get user's claims? Any idea why this one change prevents claims from coming through?

P.S. I'm using Azure AD B2C for user authentication and as I said, if I use SignalR locally, everything works which means the code that handles grabbing `JWT` token from `QueryString` is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

SignalR service will automatically inherit the claims from your authenticated user, no special configuration is needed. I just tried Azure AD B2C sample with SignalR service and the claims can be get from `HubCallerContext`.

Could you please check the SignalR access token returned from negotiation to see whether the claims are returned from server at the first place? (Decode it from base64 then you'll see the claims)

Comment: I am seeing the access token. Not to mention, if I use SignalR locally, everything is working fine. Only when I switch to Azure SignalR, then I'm not getting anything. I couldn't find any code samples on how to use `HubCallerContext`. Could you point in the right direction for some `HubCallerContext` sample code?

Comment: Could you show me how are you getting the claims? If you use `Context.User.Claims` you should be able to see claims.

Comment: I have the same issue.  My breakpoint is in the Hub code.  When running locally the Context.User.Claims object has claims.  When switching to Azure SignalR service, the Context.User.Claims object has nothing in it.

Comment: Also, I'm using JwtBearer Authentication.

Comment: I found the same issue. Exact same behavior. If SignalR hosted on a different API server with CORS in effect and uses JWT - things work fine when not using Azure SignalR service. Breaks when Azure SignalR is used.

Comment: Which version of Azure SignalR SDK are you using? There is a known issue that 1.0.1 will drop all user claims. This is fixed in later version.